# Mysql select part of field and return full value

Tags: mysql

Good day all,

I have a field called mCodes which has the exact length (7) throughout the table but with different values i.e. a few records with 5036100, 5036102, 5036103, 7010100, 7010101 etc.

I am using a select statement to first search for the first 4 characters i.e 5036 which will return all the records with 5036 just fine

I now need to return the actual full value of the records 5036100 etc. without recreating another sql statement. My statement I am using is as follow -

```
SELECT LEFT(MCODE, 4), MAKE, MODEL, NEWPRICE23 FROM mautogd1015 WHERE LEFT(MCODE, 4) = '5036'
```

I have racked my brain over this for a few hours now, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you can give us one example or sample output you are looking, that would help get an answer.

Comment: The output I am receiving is the MCODE I have asked for - 5036. I do however need to return the full field value which is 5036100, the 100 part to be added as well. My statement currently only return the value of 5036 which is what I asked for hen the statement was executed.

Comment: More clarity - The returned record shows - 5036, BMW, 320i Coupe A/T, 895 000. It should read 5036100, BMW, 320i Coupe A/T, 895000. The 100 part makes out the unique identifier for the entire record from which I need more information from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
SELECT MCODE, MAKE, MODEL, NEWPRICE23 FROM mautogd1015 WHERE LEFT(MCODE, 4) = '5036'
```

Comment: HAHAHA, I cannot believe I missed it this badly!!! Thank you Shrikant, worked a charm. Can't believe it was this simple...

Comment: No worries. It happens. :)